# Usepackage english babel - default.sty not found?

Tags: errors, miktex, babel, texstudio

I am totally new to latex. I have downloaded Miktex (for Windows) and installed it to the root directory of my local hard drive.

I have a predefined latex template. When I try to compile this template (no matter using the command line or TexStudio, I get the following error:

`Line 8: File 'default.sty' not found. \usepackage`

The content of this line in the .tex file is `\usepackage[english]{babel}`

Asking Google for answers was not helpful. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably have a `\usepackage{default}` that points to a non existent package.

Comment: Thank you I had never thought that the solution was that easy. Sometimes we are just blind for the simple things. You can make an answer from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard about a `default.sty` file. It's a risk one incurs in when using templates found somewhere, which are customized in various ways and maybe refer to personal style files that are not available to the general public.

Judging from the error message, you have a line

```
\usepackage{default}
```

that you should remove.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong `beamer` template in the current (and older versions) of [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/). It should indeed be `\usetheme{default}`. Maybe there is a similar error in other LaTeX GUIs.